# Using json_normalize to flatten nested dictionary for postgres insert

Tags: python, json, pandas, postgresql

I have the following response from an API request:

```
{u'intervalsDataPoints': [{u'startTimestamp': 1547409600000L, u'dataPoints': [], u'endTimestamp': 1547423999999L, u'tickCount': 0}, {u'startTimestamp': 1547424000000L, u'dataPoints': [], u'endTimestamp': 1547510399999L, u'tickCount': 0}, {u'startTimestamp': 1547510400000L, u'dataPoints': [], u'endTimestamp': 1547596799999L, u'tickCount': 0}, {u'startTimestamp': 1547596800000L, u'dataPoints': [], u'endTimestamp': 1547683199999L, u'tickCount': 0}, {u'startTimestamp': 1547683200000L, u'dataPoints': [], u'endTimestamp': 1547769599999L, u'tickCount': 0}, {u'startTimestamp': 1547769600000L, u'dataPoints': [{u'closePrice': {u'ask': 6169.2, u'bid': 6165.2}, u'timestamp': 1547769600000L, u'highPrice': {u'ask': 6180.6, u'bid': 6177.8}, u'openPrice': {u'ask': 6142.5, u'bid': 6138.5}, u'lastTradedVolume': 1581, u'lowPrice': {u'ask': 6141.5, u'bid': 6138.5}}, {u'closePrice': {u'ask': 6161.8, u'bid': 6159.0}, u'timestamp': 1547784000000L, u'highPrice': {u'ask': 6196.5, u'bid': 6193.7}, u'openPrice': {u'ask': 6167.1, u'bid': 6164.3}, u'lastTradedVolume': 4682, u'lowPrice': {u'ask': 6158.1, u'bid': 6155.3}}, {u'closePrice': {u'ask': 6194.9, u'bid': 6192.1}, u'timestamp': 1547798400000L, u'highPrice': {u'ask': 6204.3, u'bid': 6201.5}, u'openPrice': {u'ask': 6162.5, u'bid': 6159.7}, u'lastTradedVolume': 33408, u'lowPrice': {u'ask': 6135.3, u'bid': 6132.4}}, {u'closePrice': {u'ask': 6273.7, u'bid': 6270.9}, u'timestamp': 1547812800000L, u'highPrice': {u'ask': 6292.5, u'bid': 6289.7}, u'openPrice': {u'ask': 6196.9, u'bid': 6194.1}, u'lastTradedVolume': 31711, u'lowPrice': {u'ask': 6151.2, u'bid': 6148.4}}, {u'closePrice': {u'ask': 6267.8, u'bid': 6265.0}, u'timestamp': 1547827200000L, u'highPrice': {u'ask': 6289.1, u'bid': 6286.2}, u'openPrice': {u'ask': 6274.8, u'bid': 6270.8}, u'lastTradedVolume': 41513, u'lowPrice': {u'ask': 6224.9, u'bid': 6222.1}}, {u'closePrice': {u'ask': 6250.4, u'bid': 6244.4}, u'timestamp': 1547841600000L, u'highPrice': {u'ask': 6270.3, u'bid': 6267.4}, u'openPrice': {u'ask': 6267.3, u'bid': 6264.5}, u'lastTradedVolume': 2097, u'lowPrice': {u'ask': 6250.4, u'bid': 6244.4}}], u'endTimestamp': 1547855999999L, u'tickCount': 0}, {u'startTimestamp': 1547856000000L, u'dataPoints': [], u'endTimestamp'
```

This is my database schema:

```
timestamp|openprice_bid|openprice_close|closeprice_bid|closeprice_ask|highprice_bid|highprice_ask|lowprice_bid|lowprice_ask|last_traded_volume
```

This is the json_normalize function along with my insert code:

```
   result=response.json()
    #print(result)

    list1 = json_normalize(result, record_path=['intervalsDataPoints'], meta=[['datapoints','openPrice','closePrice','highPrice','lowPrice','lastTradedVolume']],errors='ignore')
    print(list1)

    cursor.executemany("""INSERT INTO market_data_historic(last_traded_volume,timestamp) VALUES (%(lastTradedVolume)s);""",result)
    conn.commit()
```

This does not work and returns an error

```
    cursor.executemany("""INSERT INTO market_data_historic(last_traded_volume,timestamp) VALUES (%(lastTradedVolume)s);""",result)
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

Comment: Does it return any *particular* error, and if so, what?

Comment: cursor.executemany("""INSERT INTO market_data_historic(last_traded_volume,timestamp) VALUES (%(lastTradedVolume)s);""",result)
TypeError: string indices must be integers